# How to set timeout for RestClient in windows phone 8?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, restsharp

I am calling a Webservice using RestSharp API.But I am facing a problem that when the server takes more time than RestClient's default timeout (i.e. 100 seconds) in that case I am always getting **StatusCode=NotFound**.I also tried to hard code both Timeout and ReadWriteTimeout parameters value but it did not help. Can someone suggest what can be done here?

My Code is as below

```
public async Task<WebDownloadResult> SyncMobileData(string encryptedstring)
    {
        WebDownloadResult response = new WebDownloadResult();
        var client = new RestClient(BaseUrl + Constants.WEB_SERVICE_NAME);
        client.Timeout = CONN_TIMEOUT;
        client.ReadWriteTimeout = CONN_TIMEOUT;
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);

        byte[] encryptedbytes=System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(encryptedstring);
        request.AddParameter("", encryptedbytes, ParameterType.RequestBody);

        try
        {
            response = await client.GetResponseBytesAsync(request);
        }
        catch (Exception outer)
        {
            response.ErrorOccured = true;
            response.ErrorMessage = outer.Message;
        }
        return response;

    }
```

where **CONN_TIMEOUT=600000** and my response handling class is below:

```
public static class RestClientExtensions
{
    private static Task<T> GetResponseFromServer<T>(this RestClient client, IRestRequest request, Func<WebDownloadResult, T> selector)
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<T>();
        WebDownloadResult webResponse = new WebDownloadResult();
        var loginResponse = client.ExecuteAsync(request, r =>
        {

            if (r.ErrorException == null && r.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                webResponse.StatusCode = r.StatusCode;
                webResponse.StatusCodeNumber = (int)r.StatusCode;
                webResponse.Result = r.Content;
                webResponse.ErrorOccured = r.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK ? false : true;
                tcs.SetResult(selector(webResponse));
            }
            else
            {
                tcs.SetException(new Exception(r.StatusCode.ToString()));
            }

        });
        return tcs.Task;
    }

    private static Task<T> GetResponseFromServerForMW<T>(this RestClient client, IRestRequest request, Func<WebDownloadResult, T> selector)
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<T>();
        WebDownloadResult webResponse = new WebDownloadResult();
        var loginResponse = client.ExecuteAsync(request, r =>
        {

            if (r.ErrorException == null && r.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                webResponse.StatusCode = r.StatusCode;
                if (r.Headers.FirstOrDefault(header => header.Name.Equals("P_RET_SYNC_ID")).Value != null)
                {
                    webResponse.AdditionalParameter = r.Headers.FirstOrDefault(header => header.Name.Equals("P_RET_SYNC_ID")).Value;

                }
                webResponse.StatusCodeNumber = (int)r.StatusCode;
                webResponse.Result = r.RawBytes;
                webResponse.ErrorOccured = r.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK ? false : true;
                tcs.SetResult(selector(webResponse));
            }
            else
            {
                tcs.SetException(new Exception(r.StatusCode.ToString()));

            }

        });
        return tcs.Task;
    }

    private static Task<T> GetRawResponseFromServer<T>(this RestClient client, IRestRequest request, Func<WebDownloadResult, T> selector)
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<T>();
        WebDownloadResult webResponse = new WebDownloadResult();
        var loginResponse = client.ExecuteAsync(request, r =>
        {
            if (r.ErrorException == null && r.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                webResponse.StatusCode = r.StatusCode;
                webResponse.StatusCodeNumber = (int)r.StatusCode;
                webResponse.Result = r.RawBytes;
                webResponse.ErrorOccured = r.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK ? false : true;
                tcs.SetResult(selector(webResponse));
            }
            else
            {
                tcs.SetException(new Exception(r.StatusDescription));
            }

        });
        return tcs.Task;
    }

    public static Task<WebDownloadResult> GetResponseAsync(this RestClient client, IRestRequest request)
    {
        return client.GetResponseFromServer(request, r => r);
    }

    public static Task<WebDownloadResult> GetResponseAsyncForMW(this RestClient client, IRestRequest request)
    {
        return client.GetResponseFromServerForMW(request, r => r);
    }

    public static Task<WebDownloadResult> GetResponseBytesAsync(this RestClient client, IRestRequest request)
    {
        return client.GetRawResponseFromServer(request, r => r);
    }


}
```

and **WebDownloadResult** is below:

```
public class WebDownloadResult
{
    public HttpStatusCode StatusCode { get; set; }
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
    public int StatusCodeNumber { get; set; }
    public bool ErrorOccured { get; set; }
    public object Result { get; set; }
    public object AdditionalParameter { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Do you understand CONN_TIMEOUT=600000 means how much time its ?
You got StatusCode=NotFound means 404 http server error

Comment: I didn't add CONN_TIMEOUT =600000 which is 10 minutes, at first, I started with 20 seconds, 30 seconds etc and as the server is performing some operations it takes a time to send a response. And as it takes more time than 100 seconds which is default time out, I am getting NotFound error, else for other web service it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is probably using [default HttpWebRequest.Timeout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.timeout)

Please try passing it in RestRequest explicitly like this -

```
request.AddParameter("Timeout", options.Timeout.Value);
```

You may try a better version like this -

```
var client = new RestClient(baseUrl)
{
    Timeout = someTimeoutInMilliseconds
};

var request = new RestRequest(url)
{
    Method = Method.GET,
    Timeout = someTimeoutInMilliseconds
};
```

Comment: Option is nothing but a variable that holds timeout. And that post talks about another/unrelated issue though code style copied over is much managed. It should be worth trying out these.